# Pouchdb Unable to get attachmentfrom local machine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

I'm using the below code to store image to pouchdb, result.base_64 contains the blob. When I inspect using PouchDB Inspector it shows db size as zero bite and on clicking on the attachment it shows file not found

```
 var db = new PouchDB('xyz');
 db.putAttachment('skul', 'skul', result.base_64, 'image/jpg').then(function() {
                        return db.get('skul', {
                            attachments: true
                        });
                    }).then(function(doc) {
                        console.log(doc);
                    });
```

**tried this for getting attachment**

```
db.getAttachment('skul', 'skul' function(err, blob_buffer) {
                            if (err) {
                                return console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                //  console.log(blob_buffer);
                                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob_buffer);
                                var img = document.createElement('img');
                                img.src = url;
                                document.body.appendChild(img);
                            }
                        })
```

this displays the image on browser but url of the image is

```
src="blob:http://localhost:8000/d1388aaa-f2c8-45ae-af39-e2b384e25c7c"
```

which is referring to the server not local machine

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that `result.base_64` isn't an empty string or that it's valid base64?

We have live working examples in the docs showing how to insert base64 data. You can run these examples in your browser and confirm that they work. :) https://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments.html

Comment: it's not empty, I did `getAttachment` with id and name, I received the image by doing `document.body`. But the image url refers to the remote server rather than the local machine